# Nested flexbox with scrolling area

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve this layout in the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE11:

[image: Layout example]

I can get this working with the following:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after { 
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

p { line-height: 2em; }

header, footer, article { padding: 10px; }

#parent {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: limegreen;
}

#parent > header {
    flex: none;
    background-color: limegreen;
}

#parent > footer {
    flex: none;
}

#child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
}

#child > header {
    flex: none;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
#child > article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}
#child > footer {
    flex: none;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<section id="parent">
    <header>Parent flex header </header>
    
    <section id="child" >
        <header>Child flex header</header>
        <article>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
        </article>
        <footer>Child flex footer</footer>
    </section>
    
    <footer>Parent flex footer</footer>
</section>
```

*However* some of the CSS I find a bit strange and I want to make sure that I have the most chance to not produce CSS that will break in some browser update. The reason for this is that the software will run on actual hardware (kind of like your router admin interface) and cannot be updated as easily as a regular website.

So the CSS that kind of troubles me is the scrollable `article`:

```
#child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

I fiddled around with the `height` and `min-height` to make it work in all three. Originally I had `height: 100%` only, but that didn't work in Firefox. Specifying `min-height: 0` would work in Chrome and FF, but not in IE. The combination seemed to satisfy all 3, but who is correct? Can I be reasonably sure that this wont break in the next FF or Chrome? Does this code make sense from a 'spec-perspective'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `min-height` is indeed required, and the correct way to achieve the desired layout. [From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/#flex-common):

> By default, flex items won’t shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the min-width or min-height property.

So only by setting `min-height` do you allow your your `<article>` to actually make use of `flex-shrink` and fit into the parent flex container.

If I see this correctly, the issue you see with IE matches the bug [described here](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#3-min-height-on-a-column-flex-container-wont-apply-to-its-flex-items) and acknowledged [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview):

> In IE 10-11, min-height declarations on flex containers in the column direction work to size the containers themselves, but their flex item children do not seem to know the size of their parents. They act as if no height has been set at all.

This might (or might not) encompass issues regarding overflow.

Comment: And thanks for pointing me to [https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs), very useful.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative answer: just specify `flex:1` which was missing from `#child`.**  This implicitly sets `flex: 1 1 0`, i.e. the third 0 means `flex-basis:0`.  This matters because the default initial value of `flex-basis` is *not* 0 but `auto`, which in turn effectively means `content`-sized.

[From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#valdef-flex-flex-basis):

> [The third component in `flex`] sets the flex-basis longhand and specifies the flex
>   basis: the initial main size of the flex item, before free space is
>   distributed according to the flex factors. It takes the same values as
>   the width property (except auto is treated differently) and an
>   additional content keyword. When omitted from the flex shorthand, its
>   specified value is 0%.
>
> If the specified flex-basis is auto, the used
>   flex basis is the computed value of the flex item’s main size
>   property. If that value is itself auto, then the used flex basis is
>   automatically-determined based on its content (i.e. sized as for
>   content).

Here is the modified snippet:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after { 
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

p { line-height: 2em; }

header, footer, article { padding: 10px; }

#parent {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: limegreen;
}

#parent > header {
    flex: none;
    background-color: limegreen;
}

#parent > footer {
    flex: none;
}

#child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

#child > header {
    flex: none;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
#child > article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}
#child > footer {
    flex: none;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<section id="parent">
    <header>Parent flex header </header>
    
    <section id="child" >
        <header>Child flex header</header>
        <article>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
            <p>Lots of content.</p>
        </article>
        <footer>Child flex footer</footer>
    </section>
    
    <footer>Parent flex footer</footer>
</section>
```

Comment: `flex-basis: 0` was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Tailwind (hover the class names to see the CSS properties).

The key solution is to use

```css
min-height: 0px;
```

on the nested containers.

```html
<div class="h-screen flex flex-col">
  <div class="h-12 p-1 flex-none bg-gray-400">Header</div>
  <div class="min-h-0 flex-1 flex flex-col">
    <div class="h-12 p-1 flex-none bg-gray-200">Child Header</div>
    <div class="min-h-0 flex-1 overflow-y-auto p-4 space-y-4">
      <div class="h-[600px] bg-white border border-gray-700 rounded-sm"></div>
      <div class="h-[600px] bg-white border border-gray-700 rounded-sm"></div>
      <div class="h-[600px] bg-white border border-gray-700 rounded-sm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="h-12 p-1 flex-none bg-gray-200">Child Footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-12 p-1 flex-none bg-gray-400">Footer</div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/b33HpTdUWu

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.