# Flexbox layout with two equal height children, one containing nested flexbox with scrolling content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have an `<img>` with a panel to its right containing a controls header and a long list of items. So I have a nested flexbox situation:

```
.container (flex)
 -> .child img
 -> .child controls panel (flex)
  -> .controls
  -> .content-wrapper scrolling list
```

At a very basic level, the two side by side panels are easy, being a simple flex with `align-items: stretch` .. https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/MOxYxz

At that basic level it's a duplicate question to [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height).

Once the panel on the right becomes more complex with a vertically scrolling list, I cannot see how to make the height of its parent, the second `.child`, match the height of the first `.child`.  https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/XzGJGw

```
+-------------+---------------+
|             |  Controls     |
| Left child  |               |
|             +---------------+
|             |              A|
|             | Vertically   |+
|             | scrolling    ||
|             | items        ||
|             |              |+
|             |              V|
+-------------+---------------+
```

I have read [Flexbox item with scrollable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892471/flexbox-item-with-scrollable-content) but that solves a horizontal scrolling problem, not a vertical layout like this.  Also [Nested flexbox with scrolling area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430254/nested-flexbox-with-scrolling-area) deals with vertically stacked nested flexboxes, I think this combination of `row` and `column` directions confuses my situation.

As a code snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.controls-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controls {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>In real life I am an inline img.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I want my sibling to equal my height.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child controls-panel">
    <div class="controls">
      <p>Small controls area. Panel below should scroll vertically.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not want to fix the height of any elements here.  As it happens, I know the height of the img, and so I could use CSS to force the height of the elements on the right, but I wondered if there is a 'true' flexbox way of solving this problem.

Comment: Is there something I can do to make my answer acceptable?

Comment: I really apologise for the delay.  Your answer was excellent, I was just swamped with other parts of the project right now. I read it when you posted it but you used tricks I had not seen before and needed time to experiment.  I will comment on the answer.

Comment: No problem :) ... was just following up on my answers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, for `overflow: scroll` (or `auto` and `hidden`) to work, a height constraint is needed in one way or the other, or else element's normally grow as much as needed to fit their content.

There is mainly 3 ways, where either an actual height is set, as in this first sample, where I added it to the `container`.

Stack snippet 1

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.controls-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controls {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>In real life I am an inline img.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I want my sibling to equal my height.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child controls-panel">
    <div class="controls">
      <p>Small controls area. Panel below should scroll vertically.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
      <div class="content-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or to use absolute positioning to create that *height constraint*, which an absolute element does.

It is simply accomplished with an extra wrapper, `content-scroll`, and will keep the rest of the structure fully dynamic.

Stack snippet 2

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.controls-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controls {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.content-scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>In real life I am an inline img.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I want my sibling to equal my height.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child controls-panel">
    <div class="controls">
      <p>Small controls area. Panel below should scroll vertically.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content-scroll">
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Use Flexbox alone, thought it might not work fully cross browsers, especially with older versions, that still support it but is a lot buggier.

The simple fix in your original code is to change the `flex: 1 1 auto;` in `.content-wrapper` to `flex: 1 1 0px;` (`0px` were needed for my IE version, for Chrome/Firefox/Edge one can use `0`)

Stack snippet 3

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.controls-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controls {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>In real life I am an inline img.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I am some content whoop de doo.</p>
    <p>I want my sibling to equal my height.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child controls-panel">
    <div class="controls">
      <p>Small controls area. Panel below should scroll vertically.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
        <div class="content-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Snippet 2 and 3 also answers your question

> ...with a vertically scrolling list, I cannot see how to make the
>   height of its parent, the second `.child`, match the height of the
>   first `.child`.

*Note, if the top element in the right column can grow bigger than the left column, a minimum height will be needed on the bottom element, to prevent it from collapse into 0, e.g.*

```
.content-wrapper {
  ...
  min-height: 200px;           /*  e.g. like this  */
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I tested Snippet 2 and found it did work, however using `position: absolute` seems like an uncomfortable hack.  Snippet 3 seems a cleaner approach. I had not understood `flex-basis` before.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis states "The flex-basis CSS property specifies the initial main size of a flex item. This property determines the size of the content-box unless specified otherwise using box-sizing.", am I correct that your `flex-basis: 0px` sets the initial height to zero and then the box expands to match its sibling? Perfect!

Comment: @Neek Yes, `flex-basis: 0` (or on IE `flex-basis: 0px`) means simply put that it is treated as if it were empty, hence its `flex-grow: 1` will fill the remaining space. The 3rd snippet is _cleaner_, though the 2nd has better browser support, as there might be older browsers, still support Flexbox, that might not work.